# Выборка элементов массива

Tags: ruby

У меня есть массив, в нем куча элементов и у некоторых есть `"hidden":"true"` можно ли как-то убрать эти элементы из массива, не прибегая к `each do |...|` ?

```
[
          {
            "id": "1",
            "parent": "Rabbit",
            "children": [],
            "text": "Все на работу!",
            "level": null,
            "data": {
              "description": "бла-бла",
              "published_at": 1463756982,
              "playlist_id": "Dak",
              "video_id": "T34",
              "position": 0,
              "privacy_status": "public"
            },
            "type": "youtube_video"
          },
                   {
            "id": "2",
            "parent": "Rabbit",
            "children": [],
            "text": "Все домой!",
            "level": null,
            "data": {
              "description": "бла-бла2",
              "published_at": 14637234982,
              "playlist_id": "Dak1",
              "video_id": "T35",
              "position": 0,
              "privacy_status": "public"
              "hidden":"true"
            },
            "type": "youtube_video"
          },
...............
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос решил через `keep_if`

```
videos.keep_if { |dataset| dataset['data']['hidden'] != 'true' }
```